# Hibernate schema generation consider entities from other maven modules

Tags: java, persistence, ddl

i'm using the Persitence class from javax for generating SQL scripts from our entities. And it works just fine, for the project where i'am currently in. Here is the code:

```
final Map<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(dialect.getDefaultProperties());
properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, dialect.getClass().getName());
properties.put(AvailableSettings.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.class.getName());
properties.put(AvailableSettings.DEFAULT_SCHEMA, schemaName);
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_SCRIPTS_ACTION, "create");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_CREATE_SOURCE, "metadata");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_SCRIPTS_CREATE_TARGET, target.toURI().toURL().toString());
properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_QUERY_CACHE, "false");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, "false");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY, "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());

properties.put(AvailableSettings.JPA_VALIDATION_MODE, "ddl, callback");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, "org.h2.Driver");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:h2:mem:export");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_DELIMITER, ";");

System.setProperty("line.separator", ";\n");

Persistence.generateSchema(schemaName, properties);
```

Generally it's working fine for the entities in the current project, but not fir external entites. I have a external maven module, which contains some entities i also need to be considered for our SQL script. Is there a way to define the external module in the properties, so the will be considered too ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a maven module for your entities
2. Execute `mvn clean install` in this module
3. Add this module in the `dependencies` of the project that wants to use this modules' entities.

This is all you have to do and I also applied this in many projects.
Since you did not provide what you have done in this manner, cant't help more.

So, please try these steps and if there was a problem update your question with how to did the steps.

P.S: Also if this is the first time creating multi-module project, please google about `multi-module` maven project. There are plenty of useful posts out there.